# How to flip the word from a parameter?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, flip

Eg. `www.google.com` to `com.google.www`

I have a full list of address to be flip over. It's all stored in `"queriess.csv"` How should the code be like?

```
<?php
$file = file('queriess.csv');
foreach($file as $line){
    list($ipadd)=explode(" ", $line);
    echo"<b>$ipadd  </b>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.
Providing all of the records have three parts, `www.`, `websitename` and `.ext` you can explode at the `.` and re-order the array.

```
$parts = explode('.', $address);
$new_string = $parts[2] . $parts[1] . $parts[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this..

```
<?php
$str='www.google.com';
$arr=explode('.',$str);
$arr=array_reverse($arr);
echo implode('.',$arr); //"prints" com.google.www
```

### Putting it in a function for processing all your URLs

```
<?php

function returnURL($url)
{
$arr=explode('.',$url);
$arr=array_reverse($arr);
$arr=implode('.',$arr);
echo $arr;
}

foreach($yourURLs as $url) //$yourURLs is the list of URLs say www.google.com , www.yahoo.com ...
{
  returnURL($url); //<--- say if your url is www.google.com.. it prints com.google.www
}
```

Comment: I don't want to insert the string manually. Because i have a full list inside the .csv file. So must read from the file instead of declaring as a individual string.

Comment: That is why I have given you the second part of the code as a function so you could just pass your list of URLs.

Answer (score 2):

**Explode** => **Reverse** => **Implode**.

```
$string = "www.google.com";
$words = explode(".",$string);
$words = array_reverse($words);
echo implode(".",$words);
```

[DEMO.](http://codepad.org/27MJYYPq)